# Using SUM() and VALUE()

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with invoice amounts. Each amount is a link to the given invoice. Can I use `sum()` and `value()` (or any other functions) to somehow use the *displayed* value for `sum()` (and not the actual hyperlink)?

Update: [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jUZZQgb557t7pMRVTgs1MEhMQM0u5N_06CyLJwk6Wmk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use an `Array Formula`, like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(VALUE(A1:A7)))
```

I took the liberty to edit your Sample spreadsheet.

You can write

```
=SUM(VALUE(A1:A7))
```

and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shft</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to make it an Array formula.

About array formulas (from [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291)):

> "Single-cell" array formulas let you write formulas with array inputs,
>   instead of array outputs. When you wrap a formula inside an
>   =ARRAYFORMULA function, you can pass arrays and ranges to functions and operators that usually only take non-array arguments. Those
>   functions and operators will apply to each entry in the arrays one at
>   a time, and return a new array with all of the outputs.

It basically runs a function which only takes one cell (in this case the `value`-function) and runs it on every cell in the range.